# How to use .png on APEX list instead of Font APEX graphic

Tags: oracle-apex

I am extremely new to APEX and am trying to edit a list to include a .png file (logo) instead of one of the "font APEX" pre-loaded graphics.  I can successfully select one of the font APEX graphics via this path:

Application --> Shared Components --> Lists --> MyList --> List Entry --> Image / Class --> font APEX -- Select Graphic

I have uploaded .png files to both the workspace images and the application images.  I can select them in the Image / Class menu but when I save and go to view the page, I only have a blank circle instead of the logo.  It might be noteworthy that Ithe same result occurs if I use a "standard image" in place of the application image.

I am not sure what other details might need to be included in order to make this question better, so please comment if other information would be helpful.

Thanks !